# Github revert error "Unable to revert commit"

Tags: git, github

So I was trying to revert to a previous version of my program when it corrupted. Now, in my code I have various lines of code scattered throughout that are to the effect of:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD

=======
>>>>>>> parent of 410c297... "safe version"

=======
```

etc. When I try to revert to a previous point again, it says, "Unable to revert commit, (digits) (name)

I have a very basic understanding of the git terminal, so I can't really fix it myself. Can I get some pointers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reverting creates new commits that change existing committed files. You've got a merge in progress, which means you can't revert.

Most likely, you want to reset: you want to go back to an existing commit and pretend that you haven't done any work. The most common way of doing that is to get rid of all changes and in-progress merges by resetting to HEAD like this:

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

Afterwards, if you want to go back to an even earlier version, you can `revert` or maybe just `checkout` the older version. Or you can do both at the same time using the ~ notation: `git reset --hard HEAD~3` means undo everything and go back 3 commits.

Comment: I did that and tried reverting again, and ended up getting another error. I did a status check, and got this:


`$ git status`
`On branch Pure-pixel-graphing-system`
`You are currently reverting commit 410c297.`
  `(fix conflicts and run "git revert --continue")`
 ` (use "git revert --abort" to cancel the revert operation)`

`Changes to be committed:`
  `(use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)`

Comment: I tried doing all three, and the status said that it was clean. But, after trying to revert back, it stated the same problem. Is there any reason why?

[console log](http://imgur.com/a7dfFkx)

Comment: All I want to do is be able to successfully revert again. But since I used all three, shouldn't the problem be fixed now?

Comment: I tried to use checkout, and now have [this status](http://imgur.com/DsrfJw9). It's still broken though, so how should I be using `checkout` to roll back now?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100827/discussion-between-paul-hicks-and-gamehen).